# Deploying laravel app on Fortrabbit - 403 internal server serror

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-403, internal-server-error, fortrabbit

I followed the setup to deploy laravel app on fortrabbit but now I am stuck with this error:

```
Error 403 
Internal server error
Overload: More requests than the App can handle.
A script stops with an error. Are your config files up to date? Maybe turn on debugging to trace the error.
There is an error in the .htaccess file.
Something else. Please check the fortrabbit status.
```

I have checked the configurations but I keep find a cause for that or even a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a good question to post her on StackOverflow. It's too specific - probably App- or even service-related. For such cases: please try customer support.